# efficient writing, matlab vs mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to implement in mathematica, this simple matlab loop:

```
c(1)=5;
for i=2:10
c(i,:)=c0*i;
end
```

The point is that pos has an initial value and updates every iteration.
how would u write this in mathematica?

Comment: Just use `c=c0 Range[10]`

Comment: edited with a better example

Comment: very friendly group here

Comment: I created this Q&A with the hope of helping people transition from explicit loops to *Mathematica's* higher level abstractions; I hope you will read it: [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve the same is

```
FoldList[Times, 5, Range[2,10]]
```

Ref: [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html).

Comment: edited with a better a example

Comment: @jarhead the keyword is "different"

Comment: @Kuba danks for de inglish dutoriyale

Comment: @jarhead it is not about english, it's about changing the question